# Is this a legit Star Trek quote? If so, which movie/TV episode/book is it from?

Tags: star-trek, quotes

I saw this quote on some *Star Trek* forums (quoted [here](http://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/why-was-picard-never-made-admiral.167597/), mentioned [here](http://www.tv.com/shows/star-trek-voyager/forums/admiral-janeway-controversy-378-544016/)) but was not able to authenticate it as coming from actual *Star Trek* material.

> "Well don't. Don't let them promote you. Don't let them do anything that takes you off the bridge of that ship. Because while you're there, you can make a difference."
>   —Kirk to Picard on the prospect of retirement or promotion.

Is this a legit *Star Trek* quote? If so, which movie/TV episode/book is it from?

Comment: OK, why's this getting upvotes? It was a fairly stupid question, as it turns out.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's stupid - just easily researched outside of SE.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's from *Star Trek: Generations*. :)   [IMDB Star Trek: Generations](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111280/quotes)

You can also see it on [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/James_T._Kirk) as Kirk's flag quote.

Comment: Also found [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie7.html) via [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?&q=star%20trek%20generations%20transcript).

Comment: @Iszi - Ugh... I have a tendency to *quote* my quotes in Google search :(

Comment: @DVK Given that it was obvious which movie the quote came from, I just looked for a transcript of *Generations* and then searched within the found page for "promote".  Turns out there's only two occurrences of that word in the transcript, once in your quote and earlier during Worf's promotion ceremony.

Comment: @Iszi - Generations is the one ST movie I haven't actually watched among the first 9 :)

Comment: :) I actually just searched google for "Because while you're there, you can make a difference"...

Comment: @DVK Ah.  Well, it would be the only time (IIRC) where Kirk & Picard were together.

Comment: @Iszi In canon (tv+movies), yes - IIRC, that was even how that movie was advertised.  In novels, I think I vaguely remember reading about 2 or 3 other times they've crossed paths