# What were all the occasions where the Star Trek Captains have met each other?

Tags: star-trek

According to [Iszi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31773/is-this-a-legit-star-trek-quote-if-so-which-movie-tv-episode-book-is-it-from/31774#comment60054_31774), "Well, it would be the only time (IIRC) where Kirk & Picard were together" (speaking of ST: Generations)"

What are all the occasions - in movies or TV, or other licensed material - where the Star Trek Captains (Kirk, Picard, Sisko, Janeway, Archer, Alternate-Universe Kirk) have met or interacted with each other?

(If they meet multiple times in the same movie/TV episodes, that's one instance).

Comment: @DVK I'm not quite sure this is a good fit for SE.  It's a list question that covers a *lot* of territory, and it's an indefinite one at that - since there are *still* Star Trek productions in work.

Comment: @Iszi If we're talking only about the four captains - It's a short answer. It really depends on the question...

Comment: This really does seem like a list question to me.

Comment: Opening this up to the licensed books results in a massive increase of source material.

Comment: @DVK You really need to work on this, it's a list question as is. Perhaps reduce it to the scope of your first comment.

Comment: Not every question whose answer is a list is a list question. There's only a problem if each answer is likely to list only one item. If you can clearly distinguish which answer is better (the one with the most complete answer, i.e. most complete list), then there's absolutely no problem with the question. I do agree that perhaps DVK should list exactly which characters he's interested in.

Comment: @Beofett It *is* finite... until the next movie/series/book comes out.

Comment: @Iszi ah, I missed the book portion.  And I guess with the reboot of the movie franchise, just about any crossover is possible.

Comment: @Beofett Don't forget too, that Michael Dorn has been wanting to do another series focused on Worf.

Comment: @Iszi - can you provide at least ONE more example aside from the 3 already mentioned in the question and 2 comments that would make it a "wide open list" above 3 elements?

Comment: @Iszi - isn't new Star Trek still a Kirk as the main figure? (haven't seen the reboot yet)

Comment: @DVK The new Star Trek is effectively an alternate-universe Kirk - not really the same Kirk as from TOS.

Comment: @Jeff - small scale well-defined single franchise list questions aren't off-topic. As it stands, nobody could provide more than 3 examples for this "list" - all listed in a single answer.

Comment: DVK I'm not quite sure I understand your query for "ONE more example". The problems with a question like this are many. First, the scope not well-defined. You said "main figures", and you did happen to list captains, but there are *many* more characters in each series who may (or may not) be considered a "main figure" depending on who you ask. Second, for what parts of the question's scope are determinable, this question's scope is *huge*. For one person to provide an authoritative answer, they would have to have seen *every* movie & episode and read *every* comic & book. ...

Comment: ... I personally doubt that there is one person who even *has* this entire collection, let alone has gone through *all* of it or remembers it all in enough detail to provide a complete answer. Third, the scope is still open-ended. There are still other Star Trek productions in progress and in concept which would be in-scope of this question. A prime example would be the reboot series. Others might be the Worf-centric series proposed by Michael Dorn, or any of a number of possible spin-off books or comics based on existing works. ...

Comment: ... In short, it is *very* unlikely that any one answer here will be a complete and authoritative answer. Even if it is, it has a high potential to become outdated before long.

Comment: @DVK Given the [ensemble cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_cast) nature of ST, "Main Characters" was pretty ambiguous, even with your partial list. I actually took it for granted that characters like Spock and Data were considered "Main". Thank you for clarifying. That improves the question considerably. I've removed my -1, and I'm trying to decide if I should vote to reopen. However, the whole issue of potential changes due to yet-to-be-release books, movies, whatnot is still concerning to me. How good is a question where the answer may have to be updated every couple of years?

Comment: @DVK I see you did fix my problem #1. I edited the question further to specifically call out that you're looking for, what I believe most Trekkies would call, the "Star Trek Captains". As Beofett says, that is a considerable improvement to the question. However, problems two and three on my list still remain - with problem two being perhaps the most significant. Take "other licensed works" out of scope, and I may be more inclined to vote for re-open.

Comment: @Iszi - Not being familiar with DS9, I was not sure if Sisco is, indeed, a captain. If he is, the edit works.

Comment: @Beofett - IIRC it was discussed on Meta that "there are more works coming" is not a vaild reason to close a question.

Comment: @Beofett - for example, 100% of Star Wars questions should be closed since until Lucas dies, there's a higher chance of him making more edits to invalidate any and every single one of their answers, than of a new ST series introducing tons of cross-captain meetings.

Comment: @DVK Personally, I see the open-endedness as a *much* smaller problem now that the scope is limited to just the Star Trek Captains. I think if you would be willing to further limit it to *just* the canonical films and TV series, it would be a much more answerable question - it would get my re-open vote, at least.

Comment: @DVK I remember a recent [brief discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2639/1359) that touched on it, but I do not recall seeing any community consensus on meta stating that it is not a valid close reason. Is there another discussion that you are referring to?

Comment: @DVK That's a strawman.  The amount of Star Wars questions that ask "list every instance where this happens" is *very* far from 100%.

Comment: @Beofett - Aside from "this answer will change", how is "there are more series coming" any more of a reason to dislike a list question than a non-list question? And if the reason to dislike is "this answer will change", as I noted, a non-list SW question has a HIGHER likelyhood of being invalidated by Lucas than this question by introducing new series.

Comment: @DVK it is more of an issue of "this answer will change *repeatedly*", than "this answer might change once". However, I agree that "there might be more movies/tv shows coming" isn't strong enough to VTC.  I did so more based off of the myriad books, comics, and video games. Since those are no longer part of the question, I had already cast my vote to re-open.

Comment: @Beofett You're mistaken - those are still part of the question.  It's the non-Captain "main cast" that's been pulled out.

Comment: @Iszi Ugh. I saw "non-canon" edited out, and missed that the "other licensed materials" was left in.  How many books alone are there?  How many comics?  How much material exists in video games?  That's a huge scope.

Comment: Cleaned up the comments, trying to remove only the stuff that addressed old revisions.

Comment: @Keen - I think you can remove all of mine... or better yet migrate the whole thread to chat and delete all of them.

Comment: @DVK You request magic this wizard doesn't wield.

Comment: Spock met Spock, and Spock had been a captain. Additionally, other characters became captains, such as Sulu. So depending on the requirements of your question, there are more possible answers. Additionally, if you count space stations, Picard visited Deep Space: Nine and met Sisko.

Comment: @Jason - original question was very specific to the "main" leader of each series (e.g. Kirk - but NOT Spock - for TOS. The subsequent edits kind of erased that precision). Picard meeting Sisko is exactly the kind of event I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

- Kirk met Picard in "ST : Generations"
- Janeway talked with Picard in "ST : Nemesis"
- Picard met Sisko in "DS9 : The Emissary"

Comment: Admiral McCoy and Lt. Commander Data - TNG: Encounter at Farpoint.

Comment: Picard received a call (and orders, a diplomatic mission to Romulus) from Admiral Janeway in one episode. I just watched it a few days ago but I'm not sure which it was.

Comment: @Kevin: That would be the movie *Nemesis* (already on the list).

Comment: @jwodder so it was. Evidently I forgot we pulled up a full movie instead of a series episode.

Comment: Why not time travel? There actually aren't many AFAIK that result in characters from completely different arcs meeting each other; the only one I can think of is Sisko and the DS9 crew meeting Kirk and the Enterprise crew in the TWT flashback. And technically, the Kirk/Picard meeting can be easily considered time travel because the Nexus transcends time.

Comment: @KeithS How about Sulu and Janeway then? I mentioned TWT in comment above.

Comment: Oh Oh!!!! Tuvok and Sulu obviously!!!!

Comment: Not sure if this one counts, but Crusher activates the Enterprise-E's EMH in *First Contact*, which, being a standard Mark I, is visually identical to The Doctor on Voyager. Not the same character, but the same actor.

Comment: This actually highlights a problem common to "list" questions... answers that are "here are the ones I can think of off the top of my head" or "this is probably missing a bunch, but..." are, by the very nature of the question being "what are **all**...", wrong.

Comment: @Beofett That's true, but if we're limiting ourselves to Movies and TV it should die out pretty quickly and I think it's fun if it doesn't get out of hand :)

Comment: @E.T. True, but if we wind up with a bunch of incomplete answers, it simply isn't quality content.  I think new  info in comments should be edited into this answer to make it as complete as possible.

Comment: The question very clearly indicated that this is only about the "main" character. Riker, Tuvoc etc... are all off-topic

Comment: @all - the question was about "list all crossovers", it was about "did the main character - usually Enterprise's captain except DS9 - from each series meat each other". MUCH smaller scope

Comment: Though I don't think it was shown, I think it's safe to assume that Janeway would have met Sisko, since Voyager's first episode started out on DS9.